# RxJS can not place data from Observable in another Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new to RxJS and am having trouble following a course.

I am trying to feed a list of lessons to an *ngFor using the async pipe.

I have created:

```
allLessons$: Observable<Lesson[]>;
```

so I can use

```
*ngFor="(allLessons$ | async) as lessons"
```

I am making a call to a local api which is returning the data

```
const http$: Observable<Lesson[]> = createHttpObservable('/api/lessons');
const lessons$ = http$
        .pipe(
            tap(() => console.log('HTTP request executed')),
            map(res => Object.values(res["payload"])), 
            shareReplay()
        )
```

This returns the data fine, as if I do

```
lessons$.subscribe(console.log);
```

then I can see 34 lessons in an array of objects in the console.

So how do I put these objects into the `allLessons$` variable so that it will feed the *ngFor?

When I try

```
lessons$.subscribe(lessons => this.allLessons$ = lessons)
```

I get the following error

```
Type 'unknown[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Lesson[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the same observable that gets the lessons?

```
*ngFor="let lesson of lessons$ | async"
```

Passing the data around will create more references and as the app grows it'll increase in complexity when you need to maintain it. If you have one source of truth, your observable, everything can go to one spot and get what it needs from `lessons$`

**Relating to your error**

> Type 'unknown[]' is missing the following properties from type
>   'Observable': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5
>   more

```
lessons$.subscribe(lessons => this.allLessons$ = lessons)
```

You declared allLessons$ to be an observable

```
allLessons$: Observable<Lesson[]>;
```

However `lessons` is an array, not an observable so this is why it isn't working as expected.

```
this.allLessons$ = lessons
```

Comment: The guy in the tutorial doesn't do it that way for a slightly different example, and i really want to try and understand why this doesn't work as I'm clearly not understanding something fundamental.

Comment: I updated my answer with some more information. It's hard to say without seeing the rest of your code if that will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your first suggestion but the data is not showing. I even simply did `<pre> Data: {{ lessons$ | async }}</pre>` but this doesn't show anything but the console does. I'm using a repo that I cloned to follow the course, maybe something else is going on.

Comment: I tried your second suggestion with the of(lessons) but I still get the same error.

Comment: What error? I see error in your solution. `this.allLessons$ = lessons`. $ at the end means it is an observable. allLessons$ must be a subject and it must no be assigned, but passed value like `allLessons$.next(lessons)`. Anyway, as DamianC pointed, why not just use the same observable to display the lessons?

Comment: Does this tutorial have a live stackblitz example? Something we can work with? Otherwise without the rest of the code we are just guessing at what the best solution is to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input @DamianC. Further study has revealed that I have been thinking about this the wrong way. I have just found out about the subscription Type. If I set allLessons$ to be of type subscription then I can kind of do what I wanted but in the component rather than in the template. Still more to learn. I will accept DamianC's answer because he was first.

Answer (score 1):

lessons$.subscribe not return A `Observable<Lesson[]>` , it's return `Lesson[]` object:

Replace

```
const lessons$ = http$
        .pipe(
            tap(() => console.log('HTTP request executed')),
            map(res => Object.values(res["payload"])), 
            shareReplay()
        )
```

by

```
allLessons$: Observable<Lesson[]> = http$
        .pipe(
            tap(() => console.log('HTTP request executed')),
            map(res => Object.values(res["payload"])), 
            shareReplay()
        );
```

not use subscribe.